# Receive any webpage using any kind of .Net Stream including Socket 

Tags: c#, .net, http, sockets, networking

I need to load any webpage using .net socket, so i can control how i connect and receive data myself.

**Note**

- Using WebClient and HttpWebRequest is not an option here, i need to
  use TcpClient and Socket.
- I'll be happy if i could use them(HttpWebRequest) but control the connection and data myself.
- My real target is to just load any webpage using Socket, with my own HTTP rules.

> > **Update**
> >
> > It's possible to use WebClient and control the connection and data ourselves by running a C# HTTP proxy server and using the WebClient proxy address.
> >     [#Mentalis](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/)

Comment: _"Using WebClient and HttpWebRequest is not an option here, i need to use TcpClient and Socket."_ - Why is this, if I may ask?

Comment: You know about the [`HttpWebRequest.Proxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) property where you can simply set a proxy server for the request to use? You *really* don't want to reimplement HTTP, you're going to walk into quite a few pitfalls other people have solved long ago.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes i tried it but the result is the same as using IE or Firefox when accessing blocked web-pages.

Comment: Debugging that issue will cause a lot less hassle than reimplementing HTTP, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chunked transfer encoding is described pretty clearly in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1). Each chunk exists out of:

```
chunk-size[;chunk-extensions]<CRLF>
chunk-data<CRLF>
```

The chunk-size is sent first, which is a hexadecimal number which specifies how many bytes of chunk data to expect, optionally followed by chunk-extensions, proceeded by  CRLF or `\r\n`. After you've read the specified amount of bytes, you can expect another CRLF, so you'll have to read another two bytes.

Then you can start reading the next chunk. If `chunk-size` is `0`, expect to read two more `CRLF's` (without adding it to your buffer) and then you have received all data since a chunk of size 0 indicates a last chunk.

Please note you cannot use `ReadLine()` to read chunks, since newlines in the response body (i.e. in `chunk-data`) will be seen as lines, so it'll probably return before the whole chunk has been read.

Comment: Thank you, sounds good, but i'm confused ReadLine != read till next CRLF?!

Comment: @Beygi yes it does, but you don't want to read to the next line (because a chunk can contain CRLF's), but you want to read the amount of bytes specified by `chunk-size`, plus two for the CRLF.

Comment: +1 for the closest answer till now, i'll try to use read instead of ReadLine and if it works this is the answer. thanks a lot.

Comment: Also i add here that used Read before, but i will give it a try again

Comment: @Beygi that is not what it says. You should not read until the first CRLF (since a CRLF may be present in the `chunk-data` itself), but you should read `chunk-size` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to load any web-page including a chunked webpage using C# which works with all kind of streams available in .Net

*This code is based on RFC 2616-Section-3.6*

```
public class HttpStream : Stream
{
    internal readonly Stream InnerStream;
    private long length;
    private bool canRead;

    internal bool Chunked { get; set; }
    internal int ChunkLength { get; set; }
    internal int ChunkReceivedPosition { get; set; }

    internal HttpStream(Stream innerStream)
    {
        InnerStream = innerStream;
        ChunkLength = -1;
        canRead = true;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (!canRead)
            return -1;

        var bytesReadInCallSession = 0;

        if (Chunked)
        {
            do
            {
                if (ChunkLength == -1)
                {
                    // read next chunked content size
                    string chunkLengthString = InnerStream.ReadLine(returnLineEndBytes: false);
                    ChunkLength = Convert.ToInt32(chunkLengthString, 16);
                }

                // end of HTTP response-body
                if (ChunkLength == 0)
                {
                    canRead = false;
                    break;
                }

                int toRead = ChunkLength;
                if (count + ChunkReceivedPosition - bytesReadInCallSession < ChunkLength)
                    toRead = count + ChunkReceivedPosition - bytesReadInCallSession;

                // read chunked part
                while (ChunkReceivedPosition < toRead)
                {
                    var bytesRead = InnerStream.Read(buffer, offset + bytesReadInCallSession, toRead - ChunkReceivedPosition);
                    ChunkReceivedPosition += bytesRead;
                    bytesReadInCallSession += bytesRead;
                    Position += bytesRead;
                }

                if (ChunkReceivedPosition == ChunkLength)
                {
                    // force to read next chunk size in next loop
                    ChunkLength = -1;
                    ChunkReceivedPosition = 0;

                    // discard anything until we reach after the first CR LF
                    InnerStream.ReadLine();
                }

                if (bytesReadInCallSession == count)
                    break;
            } while (true);

            if (!canRead)
            {
                do
                {
                    string trailer = InnerStream.ReadLine();
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(trailer))
                        break;

                    // TODO: process trailers
                } while (true);
            }

            return bytesReadInCallSession;
        }
        else
        {
            var countRead = InnerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            Position += countRead;
            return countRead;
        }
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        length = value;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return canRead; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

We need an advanced ReadLine as an Extension-Method on the Stream class

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ReadLine(this Stream stream, bool returnLineEndBytes = true, byte[] lineEndBytes = null)
    {
        // default end line bytes
        if (lineEndBytes == null)
            lineEndBytes = new byte[2] { 13, 10 };

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
        var buffer = new byte[lineEndBytes.Length];
        var index = 0;

        do
        {
            var byteRead = stream.ReadByte();

            // end of stream break loop
            if (byteRead == -1)
                break;

            stringBuilder.Append((char)byteRead);

            buffer[index] = (byte)byteRead;

            if (index == lineEndBytes.Length - 1 && buffer.SequenceEqual(lineEndBytes))
                break;

            // shift bytes by one to the left
            if (index == lineEndBytes.Length - 1)
                buffer = buffer.Skip(1).Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray();

            if (index < lineEndBytes.Length - 1)
                index++;

        } while (true);

        if (!returnLineEndBytes)
            stringBuilder = stringBuilder.Remove(stringBuilder.Length - lineEndBytes.Length, lineEndBytes.Length);

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```